# How can I avoid automatically attaching to T-SQL for debugging in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, settings

When debugging web sites that I'm working on, I tend to use Attach to Process rather than F5 to start debugging (since the site's already on in Firefox).  However, occasionally when doing so, I'll get the following error:

> EXECUTE permission denied on object 'sp_sdidebug', database 'master', owner 'dbo'.

I know this is caused by attaching the debugger for T-SQL, rather than just managed code (see [this blog post](http://blogs.ipona.com/dan/archive/2006/09/29/6699.aspx) for further explanation on that issue).

I'm hoping that it's possible to set somewhere to avoid attaching to T-SQL in the first place, rather than having to remember to go reset that setting each time I attach.

So, here's the real question: **Does anyone know how I can change the default behavior of Visual Studio 2008, so that when attaching to a process through the debug menu, it does not *automatically* attach to T-SQL, but only to managed code?  That is, how can Studio be set to *remember* not to attach to anything other than managed code?**

FYI, if there are project-specific settings, I'm using a C# Web Application project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the debugging engines used to attach to a process by clicking on the 'select...' button on the 'attach to:' line in the attach dialog.

Choose the 'Debug these code types' option instead of the automatic one, and make sure the T-SQL option is cleared.

I don't know how to set this as a default, hopefully Visual Studio will just remember it.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm currently doing.  Unfortunately, it doesn't remember after a restart.

Comment: New OS, new Visual Studio, and now it is remembering...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Under the properties for the project(with the project selected in the Solution Explorer: right-click and select Properties; or Press Alt-F7; or Press Alt-Enter; or select Project/xxxx Properties from the menu), switch to the [Debug] tab, and uncheck "Enable SQl Debugging"

Comment: In the C# Web Application project, I think this is the Debuggers section on the Web tab.  However, only ASP.NET is checked, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the database connection in the server explorer in VS, you should see 2 debugging options, ensure they are not ticked.

Also in the project settings, you can alter whether SQL debugging is enabled.

Comment: I'm not connected to the database in server explorer, and if I do, I'm not seeing the options you mention (not in the right click menu, not on the properties window).

Also, see my response to @James Curran in regards to the project setting.